# MXR Glimpse Regex example

Tags: firefox-addon, glimpse

Can you please share some Glimpse examples to use on MXR they seem to never work for me.

I try to search listener#edit and edit#listener and it never works. I thought # was wildcard for anything in between.

[MXR - release branch](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/)

Answer (score 0):

`listener.*edit` will match strings that begin with `listener`, end with `edit` and with zero or more characters in between.

The dot means any character, except line break, and the asterisk means as many as possible.

[www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good place to learn about regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks paa can you tell me how glimpse regex is different from regular regex.I know regex pretty ok.

Comment: Now I see that Glimpse uses agrep, so `listener#edit` should be a valid regex. Actually if after getting zero results you search again, from that page, it works.

Comment: ah thanks!!! that mxr thing really throws me off because i thought i was a regex avg-almost advanced user but i could never get that site to work. ill try out double searching

Comment: oh my gosh you're right!!! wth that has drove me crazy for sooo long!! can you plz move that to solution so i can accept. mxr searches failed for me so much i thought i was doing it wrong

Comment: hi paa im having an issue im trying to search on that site for `\W+?EventTarget\W+?` so thats a word EventTarget not surrounded by any letters but i keep getting 0 results i shouldnt though

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help, this `[^\w]+?EventTarget[^\w]+?` doesn't work either.

Comment: It doesnt work :( After clicking search on the next page load even the plusses aren't showing up, they get replaced with blank space :(